# MyBatis run native Query

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis

I want to do DB auditing, for that I need to set ee.username for the connection used by mybatis.

My question is how could I do that. I tried to look for many search results but couldn't find anything useful. I'm using postgressql and java.

Comment: Show us the configuration you use to create the connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may get it done by following method.

```
sqlSession.getConnection().prepareStatement("SET LOCAL ee.username = 'system'").execute();
```